# talend - components vs view (one data source only)

Tags: talend

Just wanted to know which will be faster on extracting the data from multiple tables (same database).  Is it better to create a view with all the tables joined as an input source, or have all the tables and connect them via talend components?

Regards,
Yin

Comment: View would be faster in terms of performance compared to Talend component. Since, if you create a view, the query execution engine of your db server will have prepared execution plan. Morever, if you have some concept in talend components, it will fetch each table data separately then if you join and do some transformation, the transformation will affect the performance.

Comment: @Viki888 thank you for your input. If you could also take a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513036/talend-parameterized-toracleinput-query-and-naming-of-output thanks