# talend - parameterized tOracleInput query and naming of output

Tags: talend

I have a view as a tOracleInput and another component for output (lets day tOutputDelimited for simplicity purpose).

1. Now I want to add a where clause to some of the fields in my tOracleInput to filter data. The idea is to pass these value as an argument during the jar execution for filtering of output.
2. Moreover, the filename of the output must came from the first argument passed from jar execution.

Anyone can enlighten me on how to achieve 1 & 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your job, create 2 [context variables](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforESBUserGuide60EN/3.4.1+How+to+define+context+variables+for+a+Job) typed string, let say `out_filename` and `where_value`.

In the `tOracleInput` component, in the query box, you can concatenate the where value like this :

```
"select * from my_view where field" + context.where_value
```

In `tOutputDelimited` component, in the file name box, you can use the context variable like this :

```
"/home/user/" + context.out_filename
```

Now you can pass them in line command like this :

```
my_job_launcher.sh --context_param out_filename='output.txt' --context_param where_value='>7'
```

Comment: how about if the filename is coming from a database column value? thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666094/talend-filename-of-output-from-a-column-value