# talend - filename of output from a column value

Tags: talend

I have an existing job:

tDatabaseInput ->
tMap ->
tOutputDelimited

For the last component, I need the filename of the file to be based from one of the columns named TYPE (which is always the same for every row). The value for the column named TYPE is 'A1' which is the same for all the records in the database.

Comment: I didnt understand `based from one of the columns TYPE` ! can you make an example please ?

Comment: I have updated my post.  TYPE is the name of the column.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many ways to do it, but here is the simplest and more readable job :

[image: talend job big data hadoop]

- tMySqlConnection_1 : Get a connection to the data base server
- tMysqlInput_1: Query the table an get only the value like this :

  ```
    select TYPE from my_table limit 1
  ```
- tSetGlobalVar_1 : key = `"file_name"`, value = `(String)row1.type`
- tMysqlInput_2 : uqery the table as required
- tMap_1 : map your data
- tFileOutputDelimited_1 : filename = `"C:\\Users\\KKL\\Desktop\\"+((String)globalMap.get("file_name"))`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two subjobs, as having a filename based on a column in your flow implies that this filename is extracted from another subjob.

You should have a first subjob getting the value of your column named TYPE into into a context variable

```
TDBInput->tJavaRow
```

TDBInput : just extract distinct TYPE column from your DB with a select query

tJavaRow : as you'll have only one row in the output, you can affect this value to a context variable : `context.myVar=input_row.myColumn;`

Then connect this first subjob to the second one (tDatabaseInput -> tMap -> tOutputDelimited)

, and use this context variable in your tFileOutputDelimited, in the filename field
`"/path/"+context.myVar+".ext"`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  TYPE is the name of the column, I'm referring to the value of the column not the database/field type.